# How can I align my chat entries to the right in the chat room?

Tags: css, reactjs

I have an react chat app, attached screenshot below. All entries with an orange vertical bar are input from myself. What I want to achieve is to put all my chat to the right side of the chat room. Please let me know what changes in message_self can achieve it. Thanks!
[image]

Below is the code to output all chat history:

```
  <React.Fragment>
    <Segment>
      <Comment.Group className="messages">
        this.displayMessages(messages)
    </Segment>
  </React.Fragment>
```

The definition of displayMessages is below:

```
displayMessages = messages =>
    messages.length > 0 &&
    messages.map(message => (
      <Message
        key={message.timestamp}
        message={message}
        user={this.state.user}
      />
    ));
```

And here is the code for the `Message` component:

```
const isOwnMessage = (message, user) => {
  return message.user.id === user.uid ? "message__self" : "";
};

const isImage = message => {
  return message.hasOwnProperty("image") && !message.hasOwnProperty("content");
};

const timeFromNow = timestamp => moment(timestamp).fromNow();

const Message = ({ message, user }) => (
  <Comment>
    <Comment.Avatar src={message.user.avatar} />
    <Comment.Content className={isOwnMessage(message, user)}>
      <Comment.Author as="a">{message.user.name}</Comment.Author>
      <Comment.Metadata>{timeFromNow(message.timestamp)}</Comment.Metadata>
      {isImage(message) ? (
        <Image src={message.image} className="message__image" />
      ) : (
        <Comment.Text>{message.content}</Comment.Text>
      )}
    </Comment.Content>
  </Comment>
);
```

In index.css, the message__self is like:

```
.message__self {
  border-left: 2px solid orange;
  padding-left: 8px;
}
```

Comment: Do you want the avatar and content to be flipped as well?

Comment: Without full CSS, we can only "guess" but If parent container uses flexbox (assuming direction: column), you can add `align_self: flex-end` in `.message__self`. and also depends if avatar needs to flip as requested by @ChristopherNgo

Comment: You might wanna write the part where you have `<Comment.Content className={isOwnMessage(message, user)}>` as `<Comment.Content className={() => isOwnMessage(message, user)}>` to run the function and get your desired values

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Yes, I want avatar to be on the right side of content if it's the owner's input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think all you need to do is flip the contents for the `Comment` block.

So for your `Comment` component at the top, you need some logic to determine what `className` to use.If the current-user owns this comment, then reverse the original layout.

```
const Message = ({ message, user }) => (
  <Comment className={message.user.id === user.uid ? reverse : ""}>
    <Comment.Avatar src={message.user.avatar} />
    <Comment.Content className={isOwnMessage(message, user)}>
      <Comment.Author as="a">{message.user.name}</Comment.Author>
      <Comment.Metadata>{timeFromNow(message.timestamp)}</Comment.Metadata>
      {isImage(message) ? (
        <Image src={message.image} className="message__image" />
      ) : (
        <Comment.Text>{message.content}</Comment.Text>
      )}
    </Comment.Content>
  </Comment>
);
```

Then in your CSS file, define a class for `reverse`

```
.reverse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row-reverse;
}
```